# Updates not received if signed in from other open id

Tags: feature-request, support

I don't receive email notifications if I sign in from open id of Stack Exchange instead of yahoo. Since all the information is linked then why no email updates? I use the same email id for Stack Exchange also.

Comment: Probably because you click the "Recent inbox messages" icon thus marking all messages as read. If that's the case it got nothing to do with different OpenID, just don't click the icon and you'll get them to your email.

Comment: i don't click the icon i also thought it was because of that only but its not.